# Approximating real numbers

Tags: nt.number-theory, prime-numbers

Given any two different prime numbers $p_1$ and $p_2$, any real number $r$ and an $\epsilon$. Can you always find two integers $n$ and $m$ such that $|\frac{p_1^n}{p_2^m} -r| \lt \epsilon)$?

Here is a very simple idea for an algorithm to work it out:

1. raise n until $\frac{p_1^n}{p_2^m}>r$
2. raise m until $\frac{p_1^n}{p_2^m}<r$
3. if $|\frac{p_1^n}{p_2^m}-r| \gt \epsilon$ go to 1.

I don't know if these three steps bring the fraction closer to $r$ with each iteration, but I think they should. However, this would not mean that they get arbitrarily close to $r$.

Thanks a lot for any help and ideas.

Comment: This is equivalent to approximating $\log r$ as an integer linear combination of $\log p_1,\log p_2$. Such linear combinations are dense owing to the fact the two logarithms are linearly independent over $\mathbb Q$.